# How can I ignore blank rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently making a google spreadsheet to help with finances and have run into a problem.

I'm wanting to take a set of data, inputted by the user and move it to a separate master sheet for future comparison - IE user inputting expenses for the month, using a created button with the assigned script within the sheet to move said data away to said master sheet and the input sheet being cleared ready for the next month. The master sheet needs to retain past data imported/pasted over.

So far I've tried just using formula as I'm much more familiar with it - however, nothing seems to be what I'm looking for as if the data within the input sheet is changed, data in the master sheet is changed.

I've had a quick look into scripts which could do this but to be honest, I'm fairly lost. It's not something I've really touched before, though I have a very, very, very small amount of knowledge about it.

Below is what I've tried script-wise, it copies over things I need and retains information, however I have to set the `sourceRange` to a specific range to combat it copying over 994 cells total. Realistically, data would extend over the E15 mark, but would vary each time the script was used. The only thing I can assume would help is for it to ignore all blank rows and take up to the last value - but as stated, I have very limited knowledge and I have no idea where to start with it. Beyond this, I've tried videos, and just general searching but due to lack of knowledge, nothing seems to work.

```
function finances() {
 importRange(
   "1wVf02IgCTQ1dY2EIJhgbOYlAOi3q19rQN4VFuobiGHY",
   "TEST EXP!B9:E15",
   "1wVf02IgCTQ1dY2EIJhgbOYlAOi3q19rQN4VFuobiGHY",
   "ScriptSheet!B2:F"
 ); 
};

function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart) {

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName())

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getLastRow(), // start row
    destStartRange.getColumn(), // start column
    sourceVals.length, // Row depth
    sourceVals[0].length // Col width
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);

};
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How are distributed the blank cells in your data data range? Are they randomly distributed or there are rows of blank cells? To make it easier for others to understand your case, please add some sample data directly into the question body. P.S. It's better to avoid using names of Google Sheets built-in functions as names of Google Apps Script function in scripts bounded to a spreadsheet.

Comment: I've included a snipped image as an example of where the blank cells would be (would be at the bottom of any input data). Where 'January 22' is would be the start of the data copied.  I have no idea how I'd go about changing the use of names of sheets within the script as it was a script found via youtube.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. When adding a screenshot please include the column and row headers (A, B, C... 1, 2, 3). It's worthy to mention that usually might be required to add a the data as text in order to make it easier for others to take the data to test the code an offer a fix / solution.

Comment: Updated image to show column/row headers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
```

by

```
const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues().filter(String);
```

Comment: Results in the same issue; copy's over blank cells in rows below.

Comment: How are you testing the changes to your script?

Comment: The script is tied into a shape within the spreadsheet with the script attached to it - works as a button.

Comment: I'm sorry, that aren't enough details. I suggest you to post a new question including a [mcve] (a version that doesn't need to read info from two spreadsheets, i.e. the source and destination sheet belongs to the same spreadsheet), include in the question body the sample data, the expected results and the results that you are getting as text, not as images.